# Summing cells which have certain value next to them AND a certain value is in another column

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xdB1Dl58aGsCOj1Xu1RZRB52Fn4RwbXDHlhuUDHZ1DU/edit?usp=sharing

I maintain spreadsheets for a sawmill. There are different suppliers and wood from them is split into different categories. What I want to do in the summary sheet, is to sum certain values from the Deliveries sheet, so I get an overview of how much of a certain kind of wood we received from a supplier.

Let's do it for "Alice" and "pine". How much pine has Alice brought in this month? I have no problem looking for every "pine" entry and summing it up, as demonstrated in the example, but I want only these pine entries, which are under "Alice" supplier entry. I assume I have to use sumifs(), but what complicates matters is that the "Alice" keyword often isn't straight to the left, because each separate truck is denoted by one supplier entry. Might sound complicated, but the spreadsheet should explain it very well.

I have no idea if there's something way simpler, but unless there is, I want a cell in the "Summary" sheet show me a sum of only those entries in "Deliveries" which have "pine" in the cell to the left AND have "Alice" in the cell two columns to the left or in the first non-empty cell above that in that column.

First obvious suggestion might be to just fill every row with a supplier name, but our actual files and the amount of types of wood are gigantic, it's a no-go. Also other sheets are based on delivery numbers, which are tied to suppliers having a single entry per delivery.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that every row has a name (in col C) for every type and quantity that is filled in. Then you can try QUERY() for the totals per person:

```
=query(Deliveries!C1:E, "select C, sum(E)  where C <>'' group by C pivot D")
```

[image: Formula 1]

and another QUERY() for the totals

```
=query(query(Deliveries!D1:E, "select sum(E) pivot D"), "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: Formula 2]